# Counting votes in a list

Tags: python, counter

I am trying to count the frequency of the elements in the list. The below code is from a Data Science book, i am not able to understand the meaning of (0)[1]
Please someone explain me.

```
from collections import Counter
def raw_majority_vote(labels):
    votes=Counter(labels)
    winner,x=votes.most_common(1)[0]
    return winner,x
l=[12,9,3,4,19,11,12,16,19,19,12,12,12,87,12,54,12]
raw_majority_vote(l)
```

Comment: When i am running the above code i m geting 12,7 as the output

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) help? Look at what gets returned

Comment: The method `most_common()` returns sorted list of tuples. Like in your case - `[(12, 7), (19, 3), (9, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (11, 1), (16, 1), (87, 1), (54, 1)]`. ISo, that's why you get `12`,  `7` as result (the number `12` appears `7` times in inputted list).

Comment: Adding to the comment of @SuyogShimpi you fetch the first element of the list - ```[0]```

Comment: @Alex when i mdoing (1)[1] i am getting an error, unable to understand

Comment: @SuyogShimpi I am getting a dictionary while running the code   
Counter({12: 7, 9: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 19: 3, 11: 1, 16: 1, 87: 1, 54: 1})

Comment: @ChayanMehrotra look into the answer given by `@Defending Troy`, you will get a more detailed understanding.

Answer (score 2):

```
  from collections import Counter
  def raw_majority_vote(labels):
      votes=Counter(labels)
      winner,x=votes.most_common(1)[0]
      print(type(votes.most_common()))
      print(votes.most_common())
      print(type(votes.most_common(1)[0]))
      print(votes.most_common(1)[0])
      print(type(votes.most_common(1)[0][0]))
      print(votes.most_common(1)[0][0])
      return winner,x
  l=[12,9,3,4,19,11,12,16,19,19,12,12,12,87,12,54,12]
  raw_majority_vote(l)
```

it will easier to understand as above showed

Comment: I have to say thank you for bringing this cool method to my knowledge.

Comment: to @Alex the index of votes.most_common(1) of this list is 0. try print(votes.most_common(2)[1]) you will get what you wanted

Comment: I would say thank you to @Defending Try ,@Alex

Answer (score 1):

just to consolidate what's already mentioned in the comments.

`most_common(n)` returns a list of tuples in sorted order with the parameter `n` specifying how many of the most common objects are returned.

for example
`most_common(2)` will return the top 2 most common objects, as a tuple with the first element of the tuple being the object name and the second element of the tuple being the count of them.
Now you know that `result = most_common(2)` returns a list of length 2, with tuples of the object and the count.
You can index into that list with `[]` and subsequently into the tuple with another set of `[]`. `most_common(2)[1]` gets you the second most common element in the list and it's count.

In your example `most_common(1)` returns a list of length 1. List indexes start at `0`, so to get the first tuple you use `most_common(1)[0]`

- To print what object that is `most_common(1)[0][0]`.
- To print how many of that object there are you use `most_common(1)[0][1]`

Comment: Thank you for the vivid explanation.